# Running a questionaire across the TeX user base

Tags: discussion

I'm in the process of experimenting with river detection in paragraphs and as part of the research I would like to get a questionaire filled out by TeX users (and perhaps users of other systems).

So I was wondering if posing a community question or so (with a link to the questionaire) would be a good and acceptable way to reach hopefully a good number of people.

Any thoughts or alternative advice?

Comment: We could also write a blog post with a link to a Google form. `:)`

Comment: I think Paulo's suggestion is great. The question would be too time-specific and wouldn't be worth saving for posterity on a Q&A site. But a blog post is the perfect medium.

Comment: Not to mention that a questionnaire is usually many questions -- also not a good fit for a single question on the site :-) @PauloCereda's blog-suggestion is perfect.

Comment: As far as i understand, the questionaire is downloadable somewhere and you want to spread the word about it. Blog-post here, a note on the mailing usual lists and others will pick it up and get the information even further.

Comment: yes it is being available separately (eventually) I haven't actually done it yet - only experimented), it is going to be google forms which will work well for it as I need to show real pictures for people to evaluate. so yes blog post is certainly a good option - basically the more people actualy do the questionaire in the end the better (even if done over a long period of time.  So in that sense it is long living which is why I thought it  be good to show up if people search for "rivers" on SX

Comment: @PauloCereda : unfortunately, the open-source and free alternative to google form, [framaforms](http://framaforms.org/), is not yet ready, but it should be in May. It rests on [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and is a part of a large attempt to [De-google-ify Internet](https://degooglisons-internet.org/). I thought it could be of interest to all the freedom-lovers `;-)`.

Comment: @Clément: ooh that sounds very interesting! Thanks for the link!

Comment: Perhaps meta isn't a bad place to advertise... any chance you could a link here to your questionnaire? ;) I for one would be happy to fill it in...

Comment: I'd also really like to do such a questionnaire for biblatex users to have some data on which to base some development decisions. SurveyMonkey allows free questionnaires which are very good.

Comment: If I understand the system correctly, it should also be possible to create a community ad that links to the survey or the blog post. That might generate greater visibility than a blog post alone.

Comment: I have a small survey for biblatex online now - what would be the best way to make people aware of this on TSE? Is there a consensus on this yet?

Comment: @PLK: Let us write a blog post!

Comment: Ok, how do we do that? I've never done it ...

Comment: @PLK we = Paulo, or Joseph or other mods I think...

Comment: @PauloCereda [Eduardo Mercovich](http://eduardo.mercovich.net/) sent me an e-mail to highlight that [Lime Survey](https://www.limesurvey.org/) is also a great open-source alternative to google form. Simple to install on a server and to use, capable of exporting the results in many different formats. If you don't have a place to host it, you can go look at [Lemiservice](https://www.limeservice.com/en/), but it seems [rather expansive](https://www.limeservice.com/en/pricing), if you ask me.

Comment: @Clément Thanks for the pointer, that's a great project! Now, if only more of it were accessible to non-French-speakers. :/

Comment: @Raphael As far as I know, all the projects of [https://degooglisons-internet.org/](https://degooglisons-internet.org/) are available in English as well, see [this list](https://degooglisons-internet.org/liste) of what they are currently hosting / developing. [Framaforms](http://framaforms.org/) is still in early beta, so I guess translating it is not a priority right now. You can contact the [Framalang team](https://participer.framasoft.org/traduction-rejoignez-framalang/) to see how things are going!

Comment: Why don't you just run the survey here using Meta?

Comment: @Clément I guess so; many of the tools they run are third-party OSS and available in English. Most of their own websites are not, though, which makes it all but impossible for me to go through their offerings.

Comment: Google Forms/Docs is privacy-invasive. I know enough people who won’t use it, so if you want to get answers from people other than the wide unwashed masses, I highly recommend to abstain from using anything Google.

Comment: @mirabilos what's so privacy invasive about it if you don't set it up that a google account is needed?  no more than posting on SX in my opinion.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach while it's true that SX uses ajax.googleapis.com (sadly) they can't snoop the actual content transmitted that easily compared to when you access their stuff directly. (Completely unrelated, but +1 to a solution that works without js, e.g. in lynx)

Comment: Here is a link to a SurveyMonkey survey for biblatex: https://www.surveymonkey.com/results/SM-SS65DP7S/